# Flash Menu into HTML

Tags: html, flash

i got this requirement, i need to show my Flash Menu into the index page and i want to change to other pages without refreshing my flash movie. its possible do that ? i tried to use frameset html tag. but want to have a unique scroll bar.

Can you please give me some tip in order to solve this.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could load the content via AJAX... But that is a workaround I won't consider, it's a poor hack in my eyes.

It'd be better to try to save the flash menu's state over different requests.

Comment: Oops, weird autocorrection of my iPod... Gotta finally disable it... I meant "poor hack"

Comment: what do you mean with "save the flash menus state over different request", how can i handle this ?

Comment: another option would be to take the conceptually simpler route of developing the site in flash. I understand though that your keen for a html solution so what is the reason for not allowing a refreshed movie?

Comment: @rfders, It depends on how complex the information is, you must save. If it's only which menu item is active, then you could add a parameter to the query string (e.g. url/?active=home) and read that from your flash file. If it's more complex, you can use "flash cookies" (they were called "Shared Objects", when introduced with Flash MX, maybe the name changed since then)

Comment: @Rob (@rfders), if the menu is flash only, I think, it's more or less irrelevant, if the whole page is developed in flash. If you can't navigate the page without flash... But ok, there are other reasons for not using flash for the whole page, like SEO...

Comment: i decided to used jquery function to reload just the content of my pages.